# Reload ajax magnific pop-up

Tags: javascript, ajax, magnific-popup

I have a magnific pop-up like

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {},
            type: 'ajax',
            ajax: {
                settings: {
                    url: some_url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: params
                }
            },
            key: 'basket_popup'})
```

first time it works fine. But assume, I have `params` like `{'zz':'mm'}`.
If I call this function second time and pass new params, I see that in network magnific sends old request. How to avoid it (except calling `magnificPopup.close()`)?

Comment: According to the docs, "if popup is already opened - it'll just overwite the content (but old options will be kept).". As you are aware, calling .close() discards the options. Why can't you close and reopen? Also, have you tried calling updateItemHTML() after changing the options?

Answer (score 2):

You could just display some dummy empty element (it could contain a loading icon) and load/reload content inside that element using ajax by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with this specific plugin, but you should be able to configure the ajax portion. Try it like this:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {},
        type: 'ajax',
        ajax: {
            settings: {
                url: some_url,
                cache:false,
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                data: params
            }
        },
        key: 'basket_popup'})
```